# Is there a way to use an existing non-Google token with GCP APIs, specifically cloud logging?

Tags: oauth-2.0, gcloud, google-cloud-logging

I've been combing through the GCP docs around service accounts and workload identity federation, IAM roles, etc., but still don't understand this.

Is there a way I can use existing non-GCP tokens in the browser to either:

- log directly to Cloud Logging
- obtain a token that allows short-lived use of Cloud Logging

I could expose a request/reply endpoint in our API gateway to create a short-lived token, but from reading the docs it seems like I might not have to do this.

So far I've setup a Workload Identity Federation for our auth provider and a service account, but I'm not sure this is the right direction.

Comment: The end result is you must use Google OAuth tokens to access Google Cloud services. Workload Identity Federation federates one service provider's tokens for Google OAuth tokens and in most cases is a good choice for supported OAuth service providers.

Comment: So far I've created a `logging-service-account` that has 
 a role with `logging.logEntries.create`, another service account with "Service Account Token Creator" role, and a workload provider. When trying to add a SAML pool, I upload the metadata.xml and get a "Idp metadata xml should provide at least 1 signing key certificate." error? But when I check the xml file using https://www.samltool.com/validate_xml.php it passes validation. Any ideas?

Comment: No idea except for this part of the error message: **provide at least 1 signing key certificate**.

Comment: The file does have a signing key cert, so I'm at a loss.